# Which is the best way to subtract a float from a pool of floats until a certain floatvalue is met

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, decimal, precision

I am trying to subtract values from a pool of values until a certain value is met, how should i do this minimizing rounding errors?
The obvious problem with this code is the +/- 0.0001 it will never be exact... is there a way to do this properly in python?

```
        for budgettodistributeto in budgetstodistributeto:
            amountneeded = (Decimal(budgettodistributeto.forcepercentageofbudget) -
                            Decimal(campaignidpercentagedict[budgettodistributeto.campaignid])
                            / totalpercentageforday)
            assert (amountneeded > 0.0)
            currentamount = 0
            while currentamount < amountneeded:
                for budgettoretrievefrom in budgetstoretrievefrom:
                    if (Decimal(budgettoretrievefrom.forcepercentageofbudget) <=
                            ((Decimal(campaignidpercentagedict[budgettoretrievefrom.campaignid])
                              / totalpercentageforday) - Decimal(0.001))):
                        daybudgetcampaigndictcopied[day][budgettoretrievefrom.campaignid] -= Decimal(0.001)
                        currentamount += Decimal(0.001)
            daybudgetcampaigndictcopied[day][budgettodistributeto.campaignid] += amountneeded
        daybudgetcampaigndictcopied[day] = campaignidpercentagedict
```

Comment: "how should i do this minimizing rounding errors?' --> Sort candidates by their magnitudes and try values closest to the running sum first.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach the problem in the following way:

```
#Function to detect if current value is within the desired accuracy  
def in_range(cur_val: float, tgt_val: float, tol:float) -> bool:
    if cur_val >= tgt_val - tol and cur_val <= tgt_val + tol:
        return True
    return False
```

a loop to decrement the pool value by some manner until the in_range function is True
Something along the lines of the following:

```
while not in_range(pool, budget, accuracy) and pool > budget + accuracy:
    pool -= (pool - budget)*dec_amt
    print(pool)
print(Decimal(pool).quantize(Decimal('.01')))
```

Of course you will have to apply your own logic to the part where you are looking for needed value.